# React, i18n, changing location after reload page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I use i18n to translate page. Page have 3 language, polish, german and english. German is default language. It works, but when I change language to german, and then I reload page location is changing to poland. Generally I know why it's happaning. German is default language, so when I change language to german, nothing is added to url. Then after reload page when my browser localization is poland, language in page is changing to polish.

```html
<div className="language">
    <span>
        <link href="{router.asPath}" locale="de"
            <a onClick="{handleClick}"><img width="30px" className={locale == 'de' ? 'selected' : ''} src="/images/flags/flaga-niemiec.png"/></a>
        />
    </span>
    <span>
        <link href="{router.asPath}" locale="pl"
            <a onClick="{handleClick}"><img width="30px" className={locale== 'pl' ? 'selected' : ''} src="/images/flags/flaga_polski.png"/></a>
        />
    </span>
    <span>
        <link href="{router.asPath}" locale="en"
            <a onClick="{handleClick}"><img width="30px" className={locale == 'en' ? 'selected' : ''} src="/images/flags/gb.png"/></a>
        />
    </span>
</div>
```

What I should change to fix it?

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation first?

Answer (score 0):

use fat arrow while calling function. like onClick = {() => handleClick()}. i will get bind to event. will not get called on first html render.

Comment: using function name without () is okay and will not call the function.